# reportValidity() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to call `reportValidity` but I want to this in jquery, which is the method that replicated this logic in jquery?

For example:

```
$('login').submit(function(event) {
  $(this).reportValidity();
});
```

this return:

> reportValidity is not a function

Comment: Try `$('login').submit(reportValidity);`. Also, make sure the selector is correct. If `login` element is an id use `#`, if it is a class use `.` before `login` selector.

Comment: This would be `this.reportValidity()` but this is experimental method.

Comment: And so, to get same behaviour across browser, you'd need something like that: `if(!$('login')[0].checkValidity()) $('login:submit').click();`

Comment: @A.Wolff okay, I did now: `if(!$('#login')[0].checkValidity()) $('login:submit').click();` the problem's that the popup doesn't appear on the `$('login:submit').click();` I mean the popup that appear when you put the `require` property on a tag and the user doesn't fill the field

Answer (score 14):

It's because `$(this)` wraps it in a jQuery object which does not support the method `reportValidity()`. It must be called on the native DOM element.
In *your* case it would suffice to not wrap it in jQuery, just like

```
$('login').submit(function(event) {
  this.reportValidity();
});
```

For clarification and adaption, this would work too:

```
$('login').submit(function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.get(0).reportValidity();
});
```

[.get](https://api.jquery.com/get/) retrieves the plain element of a jquery collection.